# External Memory and Booting

Tags: uart, flash, firmware

I am trying to use external memory on my stm32h750.

I've tutorial information about the these proccess. I decide to use below methods to use external flash

1. Write the code in 0x80000 address and enable memory map mode and jump the external flash address
2. Write the code for 0x9000000 address (external flash address) to work here (.ld and system file changed)

But I've question about the when I working on external flash.

I want to firmware update when I working on external flash, is this possible ?
When I working on the external flash, I need to press button and get some codes under uart (X modem) protocole and write to external flash. Is this possible ?

Comment: Of course it is possible. How exactly it is possible or how hard or easy it is depends on many factors you have not said, so please edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: I am using just jumping example to test. If I use the external memory for the firmware update with uart, how can I change the external start address without flash ld file ? A mean, If I working on the external flash and I need to update code, so I send to new firmware different address in external flash how can I start new firmware address without flash ld file like a dual bank logic ?

Comment: I don't understand. You compile and link the firmware to exist at MCU address X using ld file, then you program the binary to external memory so it is at MCU address X, you can't relocate it while programming. You can have your bootloader in internal Flash that can jump to address X. Or copy code to SRAM for execution.

Comment: For example my main software starting 0x90000 on external flash, I added ld file this information. Firmware starts and working than I put into firmware update (booting) mode on external flash. Than I copy to new firmware 0x910000 address. Should I change the new firmware ld(linker) file to 0x910000 address instead of 0x90000 ? Is there any method new firmware start address configure the registers ? without changing ld files ?

Comment: The address must be changed in the linker script to build the firmware to be run at certain address. But this is a different subject to your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You can make a custom bootloader that can jump to run code stored in external Flash memory, and the bootloader can be used to receive new firmware over UART and store it to external Flash memory.